# Cant get click event to change h1 property

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>JavaScript and the DOM</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 id="myHeading">JavaScript and the DOM</h1>
        <p>Making a web page interactive</p>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my html code and the js I have written is here

```
    const myHeading = document.getElementById('myHeading');

    myHeading.addEventListener('click', () => {
      myHeading.style.color='blue';
    });
```

It is very simple however for some reason the h1 tag does not seem to be turning blue on click event?

Comment: It works for me in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lk0a6r8s/

Comment: it works for me too

Comment: myHeading.style.setProperty('color', 'blue');

Comment: Good shout but didn't work..

Comment: it works for you guys?

Comment: @JoeFarrelly Yeah. Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome at the moment

Comment: Don't you override the myHeading object with some other object before click happens? You can also try without fat arrow structure (replace it with standard 'function') and do this.style.color = 'blue';

Comment: @JoeFarrelly If you `Run code snippet` in my answer, is it working? If so, you have some other problem with your code.

Comment: yea I just tried running it and the h1 stay black on click

Comment: @JoeFarrelly Did you disable javascript in your browser?

Comment: Try without fat arrow function, so replace it as I told you in the previous, edited comment. Maybe you just have an old version of Chrome?

Comment: I tried replacing the fat arrow function before posting this and still does nothing unfortunately

Comment: And no javascript is enabled

Comment: Anything in your console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Even with the 'standard' function? Try: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk0a6r8s/1/

Comment: @JoeFarrelly Also updated my answer to have normal function.

Comment: That works now brill, confused why it didn't before cheers Oskar

Comment: Update your browser ;) You can accept Arg0n's answer.

Comment: could it be anything else as my browser is up to date

Comment: Didn't you change any flags in your chrome? Maybe you accidentally switched off some features

Comment: maybe, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dom is not ready when js executed. Try this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// your code
 })
```

Comment: The code is loaded after the body is parsed, it's the last tag in <body>

Comment: @Oskar are you using `async` attribute ex: <script async/> ?